# Why are HTML tags not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
<textarea name="TT_board_announcements_content_insert" value="{TT_board_announcements_content_insert}">{TT_board_announcements_content_insert}</textarea>

<div id="board-announcements">
<!-- IF TT_board_announcements_content_insert -->
{TT_board_announcements_content_insert}
<!-- ENDIF -->
</div>
```

So my problem is when I insert content with html tags through textarea, after I save it. Div id `board-announcements` shows the content in same way as it is entered in textarea field. In other words it does not recognize html tags.

So it is displayed as this:

[image: example]

So I use this jquery simple code:

```
$('#board-announcements').html($('#board-announcements').text());
```

and with this code works.

But my question is: how to resolve it without using jQuery ?

I did tried with tinymce, but again when I save, div id `board-announcements` does not recognize html tags... it shows it as plain text.

Comment: There's no way to be sure, your code is far from complete, but perhaps you need to use `html_entity_decode()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php You could look at the source in the browser to see what it receives.

Comment: It shows that way because it's a "text area" and not a "code area". What you are attempting to do is place markup within a text area and that is not a semantically or technically correct thing to do. "The textarea element represents a multiline plain text edit control for the element’s raw value. " https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#the-textarea-element

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an attempt to force invalid markup to do what it can't and shouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `innerHTML` and `document.getElementById`, no JQuery needed.

```js
function insertContent() {
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
  content.innerHTML = text.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"><h1>Hi</h1></textarea>

<div id="content"></div>
<button onclick="insertContent()">insert content</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div name="TT_board_announcements_content_insert" value="{TT_board_announcements_content_insert}" contenteditable="true">{TT_board_announcements_content_insert}</div>
```

It's not a textarea, but this is a content editable div, which you can use for the same purpose.